# Transforming a text file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a Text file, with field1;field2;field3 in one line.
I need to produce another file that contains only the 3 fields, example below:

Original:

```
yast2-storage-lib;2.13.108-0.4.226;
yast2-storage-lib;2.13.108-0.4.226;2.13.112-0.6.1
yast2-storage-lib;2.13.112-0.6.1;
yast2-storage;2.13.108-0.4.226;
yast2-storage;2.13.108-0.4.226;2.13.112-0.6.1
```

Desired result:

```
yast2-storage-lib;2.13.108-0.4.226;2.13.112-0.6.1
yast2-storage;2.13.108-0.4.226;2.13.112-0.6.1
```

Can someone help me? I've been testing for several hours now, but I can't produce the result desired, and my text transformation skills are pretty none, as far I can see.
I tried with 'grep', 'awk' and 'sed', but as I said, i'm lacking the exp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with awk.  In awk $N is the field so to print the first and third field for example on the commandline you would type

```
awk '{print $1, $3}' <input file> > <output file>
```

There are other ways of doing this depending on specific requirements.  If you need to search for a pattern on a line such as a version and then print specific fields you would use

```
awk '/pattern/ {print $1, $3}' <input file> > <output file>
```

I would start by browsing through [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/unixnut3/chapter/ch11.html#ch11_03.htm) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).  After that I would look through awk/gawk one-liners as much of what you may need to do can be accomplished with a single line.  It may look like you cat walked across the keyboard but it could save you hours of tedious work.

Comment: Hi Mathy, thanks for your support.
I've tested your solution but I always got this:

cat sles10.4-updates.txt | awk {print $1, $3} >teste
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string

But thank you, for providing the full explanation for the implementation of the commands. I'll for sure explore this, as I'm now required to do such tasks.
I just stumble on this site during my searches, I never expected a so quick response from you and the others above.

Giving the credits according the my idea of a correct answer, BUT ALL were GREAT on Helping me.

Comment: Don't use cat in this situation, it will work but it is a bad habit to get into and is generally unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep ';.*;.'
```

selects all lines with at least two semicolons, anything in between and at least one character after the second semicolon. You might have to trim spaces off the lines.

Comment: Hi Larsmans, Thank you for your support.
This works as requested, thank you.
JG

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure you don't have trailing whitespace:

```
awk -F\; \$3 file.txt
```

If you do:

```
awk -F\; '$3~/\S/' file.txt
```

Or awks that don't recognize `\S`:

```
awk -F\; '$3~/[^ \t]/' file.txt
```

Using `;` as a field separator, print the line if the third field is non-empty.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your support.
First option works as required, the second didn't. I just thought you would like to know.

Comment: @user2348098 It appears the default mac/bsd awk doesn't recognize `\S`, I've added a non-gnu compatible version

Answer (score 2):

Using sed to delete all lines that ends in a `;`

```
sed '/;$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$ cat yast 
yast2-storage-lib;2.13.108-0.4.226;
yast2-storage-lib;2.13.108-0.4.226;2.13.112-0.6.1
yast2-storage-lib;2.13.112-0.6.1;
yast2-storage;2.13.108-0.4.226;
yast2-storage;2.13.108-0.4.226;2.13.112-0.6.1
$ awk -F";" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if(!b[$i]&&$NF!=""){b[$i]=$i;if(length(s)>0){s=s";"$i}else{s=$i}}};a[$1]=$1";"s}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' yast 
yast2-storage;2.13.108-0.4.226;2.13.112-0.6.1
yast2-storage-lib;2.13.108-0.4.226;2.13.112-0.6.1
```

Comment: @user2348098:  did you TRY this?